# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS goes into suspend even with settings turned off

Tags: 16.04, suspend

I'm having an issue where my Ubuntu is constantly going into a Suspend mode after a certain amount of inactive time.  I have the power option for Turning to screen off set to "Never" and the power option to Suspend when inactive for set to "Never".

Not sure what else I need to do?  It's on a desktop computer so shouldn't have anything to do with closing the lid or anything.

Comment: Did you ever install TLP by any chance?

Comment: I don't believe so? I'm very new to Ubuntu and Linux so I just did the default install and then did a software upgrade yesterday.